# Position link relative to image inside a div with fixed dimensions, keeping that image fit and vertically or horizontally aligned inside that div

Tags: css, positioning

I have a div with an image and a hidden button that shows up when the image is being hovered.

However, I don't know how to position the button relative to the top and right of the image instead of the div...

[image]

And here is the fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ab3vg97t/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="placeholder-container">
    <a href=<?= "index.php?page=viewPoll&id=".$currentPoll['idPoll']."&previous=My+polls"; ?>>
        <img class="resize-to-fit-and-center placeholder-containter-img" src="<?= $currentPoll['image'] != '' ? UPLOADS_URL . "/" . $currentPoll['image'] : 'assets/img/default-poll.png' ?>" alt="Default poll image">
    </a>

    <a id="my-poll-delete-btn" href=<?="actions.php?action=deletePoll&id=".$currentPoll['idPoll']?>>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.placeholder-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;

    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.placeholder-container:hover #my-poll-delete-btn {
    display: flex;
}

.placeholder-containter-img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.placeholder-containter-img:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em gray;
}

#my-poll-delete-btn {
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
#my-poll-delete-btn:hover {
    color: red;
}


.resize-to-fit-and-center {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Could you demo where you are so far?

Comment: @Paulie_D demo? like what? not sure if I understand what you are asking. what I got is depicted in the picture before de HTML snippet

Comment: @Paulie_D is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/ab3vg97t/

Comment: The problem is the set width of the container div is larger than the image.If you let the width be `auto` or just omit it...it works - http://jsfiddle.net/ab3vg97t/3/. The same applies to the height - http://jsfiddle.net/164vp0hb/. You'll just have to pick one or the other. The image isn't a square so why should the div be?

Comment: @Paulie_D the image isn't a square but the div has to be since the page I am developing needs to be a grid with the thumbnails of the existing polls... :/ there has to be a way, right?

Comment: For this to work the image needs to be wrapped in a something that is the  same size as the image. So another wrapper is required - http://jsfiddle.net/awc7hv18/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D but that solution will fail when other image ratios are used, mainly pictures with a width greater than height, they will not be centered in the div: http://jsfiddle.net/yqpdsaoL/2/

Comment: The `remove` button has to be positioned absolutely to a parent with position relative. An image can't have children so the image and button have to be wrapped together in something that is *no larger** than the image (or the positioning values won't work. It looks like it works to me in your second example. Of course you could use fixed px values for positioning the button is you want. - http://jsfiddle.net/yqpdsaoL/4/ **If you are referring to vertically centering a horizontal image, that wasn't part of your original question**

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, I also wish to keep horizontal images vertically aligned :/ sorry if that was not clear.. http://jsfiddle.net/yqpdsaoL/5/ this fiddle gets the delete button positioned correctly but won't vertically align horizontal images :/ maybe the question title should have been: how to position a link relative to an image inside a div, keeping that image vertically or horizontally aligned, and also fitted in that div (which btw has fixed dimensions)

Comment: Not impossible...but I think it might require a different structure and I doubt if it would be responsive.

Comment: ok :/ thanks for all the help though @Paulie_D! :)